# Customize Table of Contents Scheme

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to devise and utilize a customized scheme for the table of contents. I have exposure to LaTeX, but not expertise. Thus I request assistance with a solution that is straightforward/easy to understand, effective, and requires minimal effort to implement.

I've defined two environments *Question* and *Example* which I would like to include within the indexing scheme as well.

The desired scheme is as follows:

## Unit 1

### Lecture 1

##### 1.1 Experimental Design

###### 1.1.1 *e.g.*

###### 1.1.2 *e.g.*

###### 1.1.3 *e.g.*

###### 1.1.4 *q.*

##### 1.2 Statistical Modeling

##### 1.3 Hypothesis Testing

###### 1.3.1 *e.g.*

###### 1.3.2 *q.*

### Lecture 4

##### 2.1 Covariance

###### 2.2 Correlation

###### 2.3 Least Squared Regression

...

###### 2.7 Backwards Model Selection

### Homework 1

##### 3.1 Problem 1

##### 3.2 Problem 2

##### 3.3 Problem 3

...

##### 3.6 Problem 6

### Project 1

##### 4.1 Design Sketch

##### 4.2 Results

Is there any assistance you can offer? Thank you in advance.

**As per the comments below I've included the code utilized to compile for the example output shown below :**

*main.tex*

```
\documentclass{article}

%Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Commands
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}

\newcommand{\Implies}{ \quad\implies}
\newcommand{\Prob}{\text{I\kern-0.15em P}}
\newcommand{\Expec}{\text{I\kern-0.15em E}}
\newcommand{\Variance}{\operatorname{Var}}
\newcommand{\Vector}[1]{\bm{#1}}

%Environments
\newenvironment{example}
    {\\~\\
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
    \hline\\
    }
    {
    \\\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
 \subsubsection{ \emph{e.g.}}
    \end{center}
    \\~\\
    }

\newenvironment{question}[3][Q:]
{\\~\\\begin{center}
\underline{#1 #2} \begin{quote}
    ``#3''}{\end{quote}\end{center}\\~\\}

% Settings
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor= black,
filecolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage


% Sections
\input{sections/Unit 1/Unit 1.tex}
\input{sections/Unit 1/Lecture 1.tex}
\input{sections/Unit 1/Lecture 4.tex}
\input{sections/Unit 1/Problem Set 1.tex}


% Bold Principles
% Italicize concepts

% Bibliography
%\newpage
%\nocite{*}
%\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

*Unit 1/Unit 1.tex*

```
\newpage
\part*{Unit 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Unit 1}
```

*Unit 1/Lecture 1.tex*

```
\newpage
\section{Lecture 1}
\subsection{Experimental Design}
\begin{Example}
\end{Example}
\begin{Example}
\end{Example}
\begin{Example}
\end{Example}
\subsection{Statistical Modeling}
```

*Unit 1/Homework 1.tex*

```
\newpage
\section{Homework 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Homework 1}

\subsection{Problem 1.1}
\subsection{Problem 1.2}
```

Currently, I've been able to produce this so far:
[image: Current Output]
The *Example* environments have been included as by the *e.g.* tag.
However, The *Question* environment has not been included.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  We really need more information to be able to help effectively -- guessing isn't very often accurate.  Please provide a small compilable example showing what you've already done.  It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.  Then potential helpers can copy and paste to experiment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've included the LaTeX code I wrote which I used to compile the example output contained within the post. Does that help? Do you need more detail?

Comment: @cfr Thank you; I've removed the 'index' terminology from the post. I'm only asking about the Table of Contents at this point.

Comment: @cfr I use \part* because I don't want the unit pages to be numbered within the table of contents.  I used \addcontentsline because the \tableofcontents command includes numbers for every section/subsection/subsubsection etc. which I do not want. 

Yes, I want the Table of Contents numbering to be exactly as specified. I don't want to assume that lectures/problems are exactly one-to-one mapped to the table of contents numbering. 

Will captions be included within the table of contents automatically via \tableofcontents? what custom command or wrap should I use?

Comment: @cfr I've created custom environments (example & question) which I want to be included within the Table of Contents by default. I don't know how to do that. 
I'm adding table of contents numbering manually because I don't agree with the automatic/default system. If you're able to assist via providing actual LaTeX code which compiles to the desired output or recommend an easy-to-follow reference for the topic, that would be most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @cfr I understand and agree with your remarks regarding the Example environment. I'd much rather have the example and its caption be paired together. However, I don't want to use \caption because it is not include within Table of Contents, but rather List of Figures/List of Tables. I need the examples to be within Table of Contents. If you have a better definition of environment example, please share!

Comment: @cfr I'm not going to dive into the reasons too much; suffice it to say, that Lecture Y may not be assumed to be numbered Y within the Table of Contents de facto. Let me handle the confusion; if you're able to help me with the numbering schema, please share! Thanks.

Comment: OK. I'm going to tidy up my comments here, so you might like to do the same ;).

Comment: You're defining a custom environment anyway. Assuming you don't want a float, use `\captionof` and and add the contents line into the definition of your environment, so you don't have to do it manually and you don't encourage a page break. If you want to disallow page breaks, you can put the stuff into a box or something like a `minipage`, but you'll get poor spacing if they don't float. *But you should not be using `\\ ` for vertical spacing.* You'll get lots of box warnings and poor spacing generally. `\baselineskip\par` is much better unless you're in a `tabular` or something.